# AngularUI Typeahead: Event if no result is found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Does anybody know a way to check if none of the results match the input. Or at least, can i access the results array? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add `typeahead-no-results="noResults"` to your input

and put this beneath the input.

```
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```

Docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead